# SELECT statement within a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following T-sql code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATEPART(DW, [DATE]) AS datepar,
    DATENAME(dw, [Date]) AS dy,
    EDEN = (SELECT SUM(total) AS UnusedTotal 
            FROM [dbo].[CHEA_CCG_Report] ccg  
            WHERE availability = 'Available' 
             AND [Name of the Location of the Session] in ('Cumberland Infirmary'))
FROM 
    [dbo].[CHEA_CCG_Report] ccg
```

However, the code is returning the total of the sum against everyday. How would I reference it so that it brought back the sum just for that day?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the table structure.

Comment: You should really be using GROUP BY or PARTITION BY windowing function. What do you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Joe,  Basically I am wanting to see against the weekdays how many unused sessions there was by practice (EDEN) against the (Cumberland Infirmary).  At the moment in time it is putting the total sum against the all the weekdays.

Comment: Adding the line `GROUP BY datepart(DW,[DATE]), datename(dw,[Date])` after your FROM line, and removing the `distinct` keyword from the SELECT statement should give you what you are looking for. But if you really want to use the separate SELECT statement, you need to tie it to the day of the week on your inner query to that on your outer query. This is more complex in this case, and not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a `GROUP BY` and use those conditions in the `WHERE` clause ?

(Untested)

```
SELECT
DATEPART(dw, [Date]) AS [datepar],
DATENAME(dw, [Date]) AS [dy],
SUM(total) AS EDEN
FROM [dbo].[CHEA_CCG_Report] AS ccg
WHERE availability = 'Available'
  AND [Name of the Location of the Session] IN ('Cumberland Infirmary')
GROUP BY DATEPART(dw, [Date]), DATENAME(dw, [Date])
ORDER BY [datepar], [dy]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(DW, [DATE]) AS datepart, 
       DATENAME(dw, [Date]) AS dy, CCG1.UnusedTotal AS EDEN
FROM [dbo].[CHEA_CCG_Report] ccg OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(ccg1.total) AS UnusedTotal,  . . .  
      FROM [dbo].[CHEA_CCG_Report] ccg1
      WHERE ccg1.availability = 'Available' AND
            ccg1.[Name of the Location of the Session] IN ('Cumberland Infirmary') AND
            ccg.[DATE] = ccg1.[DATE]
     ) ccg1;
```

Assuming the `[DATE]` has `DATE` type only else you would need to do conversations.

Comment: If done this way, it should be a CROSS APPLY, since entries are guaranteed to exist. However, a GROUP BY and SUM in the outer query should be sufficient, so a CROSS APPLY shouldn't be needed. Why requery a table when you don't need to?

Comment: @LaughingVergil. . .  I just simplifying the question with answer & i can't assume that you had.

Comment: Thanks! that seems to work... can you add mulitple applys for example EDEN is only one practice but I would need to add another -- using the same SUM method

Comment: @Choc. . .  If the same parameters available, then do other aggregation inside `outer apply`.

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer. Please take a moment to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It lets other users know the question has an answer, and rewards the user who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.